# how does continuous exports work when the same release is available from two different apps?

Tags: azure-application-insights, visual-studio-app-center

Suppose two different apps in App Center (let's call them X and Y) are configured to continuously export telemetry to two separate Application Insights resources (let's call them X and Y as well).  If a single release (binary) is available from two different apps in App Center, which AI resource will receive the telemetry data?

I would *hope* that it depends on which app the user installed the release from. (if installed from App X, then telemetry data would go to AI resource X.)  But I suspect that the telemetry data might be sent to *both* resource X and Y.  Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to App Center support individual,

> The data should depend on which app the user installed the release from.

But this was wrong.

In my research, I discovered that our app programmatically configures itself to be associated with a particular app in AppCenter (which, in turn, specifies a configuration for continuous exports) by specifying its app secret in the call to AppCenter.Start(appSecret).  The use of this method is described here: [Getting Started with Xamarin: Start the SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin#4-start-the-sdk).

So, I think that’s my answer: it doesn’t matter which App Center app you’ve distributed the binary to.  What determines where the app telemetry will go is determined by the call to AppCenter.Start().  Specifically, it uses the export configuration from the app specified by the app secret passed to Start().